# Android Enterprise Build - Hard Authentication

Tags: android, authentication

We are in process of publishing an Enterprise build in market. This product has a restriction, as to until this product is not 'Authorized' by our web-services, user will not be able to use it, and eventually will see 'You are not authorized to use this product'...

My question is around the policies of Android Market place: Do they have a restriction on Hard authentication. Since my application will not be of any use till the time it gets authenticated.

Does this stand a chance to get rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not reject applications on the basis of these criteria. This is simple use case for applications to do authentication through server. You can also chose to distribute your enterprise application in-house. You can distribute application .apk file through e-mail or host the file on your website. Please visit this link to read more about distribution or development of Android enterprise applications:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#how